# How do I mock the DB models?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to test a repository and so need to mock the Model Container. Really all I need is to be able to set the Blogs returned to GetBlogs() in the BlogRepository. The repository code is:

```
private BlogWebsiteModelContainer context;

public BlogRepository(BlogWebsiteModelContainer context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public IEnumerable<Blog> GetBlogs()
{
    return context.Blogs;
}
```

So I want to be able to set what `context.Blogs` is. I am using Moq and have tried the following:

```
var mockBlogSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
context.Setup(m => m.Blogs).Returns(mockBlogSet.Object);
blogRepo = new BlogRepository(context.Object);
```

But I get this error message when I debug:

Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.Blogs

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx. And so my code became the following:

```
List<Blog> blogs = new List<Blog> 
{ 
    new Blog() { Id = 1 },
    new Blog() { Id = 2 },
    new Blog() { Id = 3 },
};

var data = blogs.AsQueryable();

var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var mockContext = new Mock<BlogWebsiteModelContainer>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

blogRepo = new BlogRepository(mockContext.Object);
```

Then I had to go into my BlogWebsiteModelContainer class and change:

```
public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
```

Just adding the `virtual` in. And it all worked.

Quick note: reason for creating the list first and then making it `.AsQueryable()` was so in my code I had the original blog list separate so I could compare it in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface for your BlogWebsiteModelContainer, then mock the interface.  Also instead of defining `Blog`s on the interface as `DbSet<Blog>` define it as `IQuerayable<Blog>`

You can then create a List and use the `.AsQueryable` extension:

```
var contextMock = new Mock<IBlogWebsetModelContainer>();
var mockBlogSet = new List<Blog>();
contextMock.Setup(m => m.Blogs).Returns(mockBlogSet.AsQueryable());
blogRepo = new BlogRepository(contextMock.Object);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it wasn't really working for me. Creating the interface was not straight forward, maybe due to some complexities in my project. You did set me on the right path though with the AsQueryable() point. Thanks.